# How to set textShadow Property

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement the `textshadow` in my text, placed in a `<a href="#">`, I am doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById("text").style.textShadow("1px 1px 0 red");
document.getElementById("text").style.moztextshadow("1px 1px 0 red");
document.getElementById("text").style.webkittextshadow("1px 1px 0 red");
```

None of the above implementations work. Am I making some kind of mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this on this stackoverflow page:

```
document.getElementById('question-header').style.textShadow = '2px 2px 0 cyan';
```

edit: This seems to work on webkit browsers. Units are normally required, but not with 0. To debug, you can print out values for document.getElementById('text'), then that.style.

Answer (score 1):

```
element.style["text-shadow"] = '1px 1px 5px red';
```

- `element.style.*` is not a function, it's a
  value.
- You must specifiy the third value in `text-shadow`. Giving 0 will give no blur-shadow to the text, more like a drop shadow.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the 0. A zero with no units in this case is 0px.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 0 red";
text.style.mozTextShadow = "1px 1px 0 red";
text.style.webkitTextShadow = "1px 1px 0 red";
```